# fasteR searching for specfic mail on mail server using java mail api

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Is there any way to do search faster for mail matching certain criteria using java mail API?
I have used FetchProfile and folder.search(), but it takes long time, when there is huge chunk of messages on the mail server.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using IMAP and Folder.search, all the searching should be done on the server.  How fast the search is depends on your server, the complexity of the search, etc.  You can turn on [JavaMail debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to see the exact IMAP commands sent to the server and the server's response.  If you measure the time of just the Folder.search call, and the call is sending the expected IMAP SEARCH command, then you're doing the best you can.

Comment: thanx for the reply, It takes up to 50-60 seconds to search, if the folder I'm searching contains >10000 messages. Is there any altenate to this to get a much faster result?

Comment: that's alternate soution, but may be there is third party API which reduces the time complexity of searching for a mail. is it?

Comment: You need to ask your server vendor.  Some servers support non-standard protocols, which might offer a different search capability.  But there's lots of IMAP clients so most servers do a good job of optimizing that case.  Exactly what SEARCH command are you sending that takes so long?

Comment: `folder = store.getFolder("inbox");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    messages = folder.getMessages();
    SearchTerm term = new HeaderTerm("mailHeaderId", headerId);
    messages = folder.search(term);`
mailHeaderId is custom header Id, I am using and headerId the argument i m passing.

Comment: Some servers are probably less efficient searching for custom headers.  They might not keep any sort of index of all headers to make such searches more efficient.  If you use a SubjectTerm, does the search take the same amount of time or is it faster?  You should really ask your IMAP server vendor about this.  What IMAP server are you using?